# How can I prevent slickR carousel stacking upon user clicks in a tab panel?

Tags: shiny, carousel, slick.js

I am very new to R Shiny and have just come across slickR. I am hoping to use it for a data visualization app I am developing for a project I am working on looking at zooplankton isolates.

My Shiny app works by taking user input from a sidebar panel to select an option for an isolate that the user would like to view photos and data for. What I am hoping for is that when you click to select an isolate and then click on the tab for photos and videos, that you will see the slickR carousel with photos of just that isolate.

The issue I am having is that the carousel will appear normally for the first selection, but when the user clicks on the second selection from the drop-down menu on the sidebar, the carousel for the first isolate appears on top of the one for the second isolate, and the carousels continue stacking on top of each other with every click of a different isolate.

This is what I currently have in the main panel:

```
main_content <- mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
    tabPanel("About", br(), em(textOutput("text1"))
  ),
  tabPanel("Photos & Videos", br(), em(textOutput("text2")), br(), slickROutput("slickr", width = "500px"), br(), br(), splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"), imageOutput("image1"), imageOutput("image2")), br(), br(), uiOutput("video")),
  tabPanel("Growth Curves", br(), splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"), plotOutput("plot1"), plotOutput("plot2"))),
  tabPanel("Compare", 
    splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"), imageOutput("image3"), imageOutput("image4")))
  )
)
```

This is what I have in the server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

# Output slickR Carousel:
  output$slickr <- renderSlickR({
    if(input$selectIsolate == "BBSS24"){            
       imgs <- list.files("~/Desktop/MAPEL/MAPEL R PROJECTS/BBSS/www/BBSS24/carousel", pattern=".jpg", full.names = TRUE)
       slick <- slickR(imgs, slideId = 1, height = 100, width = "95%")+ settings(dots = TRUE, autoplay = FALSE, autoplaySpeed = 1000)
    }
    else if(input$selectIsolate == "BBSS25"){
      imgs1 <- list.files("~/Desktop/MAPEL/MAPEL R PROJECTS/BBSS/www/BBSS25/carousel", pattern=".jpg", full.names = TRUE)
      slick1 <- slickR(imgs1, slideId = 2, height = 100, width = "95%")+ settings(dots = TRUE, autoplay = FALSE, autoplaySpeed = 1000)
    }
...
})
```

This is what I want the carousel to look like when you select an isolate from the drop-down menu (only the carousel with images for that particular isolate shown):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TeLP.png)

And this is what keeps happening when you select a different isolate (what I want to avoid):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg49n.png)

If anyone has a clear answer as to how I can fix this please explain as simply as possible with code fixes as I am extremely new to this! Thank you!